# Can I run an application compiled in Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 98?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-98

I have built a program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and it works fine.

The problem I am having is the the machine it needs to be used on is running windows 98. As far as I can tell I need to install the re-distributable for vc++. Can I install the re-distributable on windows 98 or is there a way to make it work on windows 98?

Comment: My sincere condolences that you have to use windows 98 :)

Comment: You have to install the redistributables, yes. If it works, it works. If not, MS will tell you that it is unsupported.

Comment: All of the other answers so far elide several important details. They're short and sweet, which seems nice at first blush, but they won't get you very far. There's more to the story than just getting the redistributable installed. The Windows 9x platform is a *very* different beast than the NT platform that we all know and love now. I've tried to explain as many of the possible snags and solutions in my answer, but let me know if you run into any problems I didn't discuss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, apps compiled with VS 2005 work perfectly fine on Windows 98 and Me. I've run several of them myself, and keep VS 2005 around and installed for precisely this purpose. [Version 2005 of the CRT redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387) is supported as far back as Windows 98.

The trick is that **you must compile the application for the multi-byte character set (MBCS)**. It will not work when compiled as Unicode, which is the default project setting. Windows 9x platforms do not support Unicode without some extra help. You should be able to change the project settings and be fine, but if you've written your code to assume Unicode, then you'll have a problem.

This is why you need to use generic character types and functions defined in `tchar.h`, rather than their wide character equivalents that are preferred for Unicode builds. Always define strings using the `TCHAR` type (or `LPTSTR` or `LPCTSTR` types), which is conditionally defined to `wchar_t` or `char`, as appropriate. Use string manipulation functions that begin with `_tcs...`, rather than the ones specific for wide or narrow characters. Make sure that when you call functions, you always call the generic typedef'ed versions, rather than the ANSI- or wide-specific ones that end with an `A` or a `W` suffix.

It may be a lot of work to go back and fix this if you haven't done it from the start. If that's the case, you might look into the [Microsoft Layer for Unicode on Windows 95/98/ME Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688166), which provides an abstraction layer that allows you to call Unicode functions on the legacy Windows 9x operating systems where they are not natively supported.

Beyond Unicode/MBCS, the only thing to watch out for is that you're not calling any functions that didn't exist in the Win32 APIs way back in the Windows 98 days. You can't trust what the online MSDN documentation tells you for the "minimum supported client version" anymore, because Microsoft is no longer supporting Windows 98. *All* of the SDK docs say that the minimum supported version is Windows 2000 now, and you know that's not correct. The entire API was not introduced as late as W2K. In order to get accurate information, you'll need to obtain an old version of the SDK documentation; what came with your installation of VS 2005 should be fine. The information there goes back at least as far as Win 98, if not 95 (I don't remember exactly).

For instances where you want to call functions that didn't exist back in Windows 98 when you're running on newer systems where they *are* available, you'll need to take extra care to call them *dynamically*, rather than adding them to your application's DLL import table (what the linker generally does for you automatically). That means defining function pointers yourself, and using the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212.aspx) functions to call them. It's not fun, but it *does* work.

Alternatively, you can configure the linker to "delay load" the libraries (check your project's properties). This is much more convenient, but obviously you'll need to ensure that you *only* call the functions that are available on your target operating system, otherwise the application will crash.

Either way, the [`GetVersionEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451.aspx) will tell you everything that you need to know about the current host operating system so that your code can take different paths (calling newer functions if available, or falling back to older ones if not) depending on the environment. This allows you to support new functionality on new systems, while still retaining whatever degree of support for legacy operating systems is appropriate. You'll find a lot of `if` statements in the code base when this is done right. :-)

Comment: An addendum from the future of 2015 - if you use KernelEx you can run newer software on 98SE, and avoid a lot of the compatibility traps even in contemporary development software like VS2005 if not just run the existing software outright (if it was developed for XP - if it requires newer than that your chances decrease).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387 (Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86))

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, **Windows 98**, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the system requirements?  According to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387), Windows 98 should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is more  than distributing CRT with your application. All functions you use in the program must be available in Windows98. For all the functions you find on MSDN you will find a "Minimum supported client". This is tricky ...
To get over CRT issue you can statically link the application (/MT linker option). Will result in a bigger binary but will work.

Comment: That information is no longer accurate. By "minimum supported client", they refer to the minimum client operating system that Microsoft still supports, not the minimum that supports the function call in question. Lots of the functions exist on Windows 98 and call be called without a problem. But they list Windows 2000 as the minimum supported client because Microsoft no longer supports Windows 98. You need to obtain old versions of the MSDN documentation to get accurate information about support on legacy operating systems. The MSDN help that comes with his VS 2005 installation will work fine.